# CSS3 Rotate on animated element causing click event not to invoke

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, transform

Okay this one is causing me a lot of problems.

When using the css3 `-webkit-transform` style with any kind of 3d rotation (such as `rotateY(30deg)`), it is extremely unreliable to bind a click event to this rotated object.

See the example code below or look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyvtZ/1/) (to see the unreliability in fiddle, click on the right side of the element). This example does not have animation but still is affected.

html:

```
<div id='box1'>Click this box.</div>
```

css:

```
#box1{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```

jquery:

```
$('#box1').click(function(){
    alert('clicked box 1');
});
```

What I mean by 'unreliable' is that the click event is not always thrown (depending on where you click it), and sometimes the event is not thrown at all (no matter where you click it).

Is there a way to fix or avoid this so it works with CSS3 elements while rotated and animated?

**Update:**

Using the CSS property 'float:left' on the element seems to allow it to detect click events properly ***while not in motion**. Does anyone know why the float property fixes this?

My ultimate goal is to have the object receive click events while in motion, however, when I apply a new CSS3 rotate3d property (live, upon another jquery event) to give the object animation, the click event starts failing again.

Comment: Adding a `float:left;` makes it work : http://jsfiddle.net/RyvtZ/4/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PranavKapoor interesting this works, how did you come up with this? I am still having problems for rotated objects in the middle of a transition though, so this is not a complete solution

Comment: @JustinGingyMcDonald, provide a new jsFiddle with the **type of animation your using** if you still have issues, as the OP's animation works correctly in Chrome for me.

Comment: @PranavKapoor, I too would like to know how you arrived at this solution, but more importantly if using float attribute isn't possible, then what other attributes will work? IMHO, I was stumped in finding a solution to this interesting issue.

Comment: An alternative route to solve this problem could be to wrap the elements in a container each and detect clicks on the container instead of the rotated element.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot seem to replicate the problem, it seems to be working correctly after adding a `float:left;`.

Sometimes browsers act funny while rendering the actual width of an HTML element. `float:left` seems to make the browsers calculate better.

This is the JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#box1').bind({
    'click' : function () {
      alert('clicked box 1');
    },
    'hover' : function () {
      console.log('Over Box 1');
    }
  });
  $('#box2').click(function(){
    alert('clicked box 2');
  });

  window.angle = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    if (window.angle >= 360) {
      window.angle = 0;
    } else {
      window.angle += 5;
    }
    $('#box1').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + window.angle + 'deg)');
    }, 100);
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle with the animation, it seems to work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/RyvtZ/9/

(I added `console.log` on `hover` to make life simpler ;) )

Comment: Thanks @PranavKapoor, sorry my question is very vague. I will update it in a little while if I still cannot find a solution. I need to use the css3 `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform Xs linear` with X = some amount of delay. This way the 3d rotation animation will be smooth. This is where I am finding my problem.

Comment: **+1** Excellent solution! I would like to ask that `display:inline-block;` then isn't required due to use of `float:left` or `float:right` usage?