# CSS3 Rotation transition causing intermittent mouse click detection

Tags: html, css, onclick, css-transitions, css-transforms

This is a very similar issue to [CSS3 Rotate on animated element causing click event not to invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833227/css3-rotate-on-animated-element-causing-click-event-not-to-invoke?answertab=active#tab-top)

Although my issue is a tad different, plus can't comment on it to add supporting information.

Checkout my sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/5bsG3/2/

I have a span inside a link which rotates around the Y axis, on mouse hover. The click event (for jQuery or simply for link navigation) is not always detected. Try clicking on the padded region of the link (just off the text but on the link). It's almost as if  there's an issue with hit detection because the span is spinning and thus at angles where the mouse isn't clicking on the span. Even though the mouse still clicking on the padded region of the LINK. Angles around 70-110deg seem to be the problem.

The proposed solution in the aforementioned post doesn't actually fix this issue. Also, my issue maybe a tad different since my rotation is handled as a CSS transition instead of a JS interval trigger.

Any thoughts? Has anyone seen this before? I know this is a cheesy way of doing links but for the target website, it's an acceptable amount cheese.

Feel free to simplify the jsfiddle, I started simple and added a bit of debugging info to help identify the problem.

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="" class="flip-link"><span>Click this link</span></a></li>
  <li id="LinkCounter">LinkClicked</li>
  <li>&nbsp</li>
  <li id="SpanCounter">SpanClicked</li>
<ul>
```

css:

```
ul li
{
    display: inline;
    float: left ;
}

.flip-link
{
    float:left ;
}

span
{
    float:left ;
}


.flip-link {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 50px 7px 50px ;
    margin-right: 10px ;

    background: #AAA;

    -webkit-perspective: 50px;
       -moz-perspective: 50px;
        -ms-perspective: 50px;
            perspective: 50px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
            perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.flip-link span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;

    background: #EEE;

    padding: 0px 10px ;

    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
            transition: all 1000ms ease;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
    .flip-link:hover span
    {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px ) rotateY( 360deg );
           -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px ) rotateY( 360deg );
            -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px ) rotateY( 360deg );
                transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px ) rotateY( 360deg );

        color: #55FF55 ;
    }
```

JS:

```
var linkClickCount = 0 ;
var spanClickCount = 0 ;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip-link').click(function () {
            linkClickCount++ ;            
            $("#LinkCounter").text(linkClickCount);

            return (false);
    });

    $('.flip-link span').click(function () {
            spanClickCount++ ;            
            $("#SpanCounter").text(spanClickCount);
    });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that mouse clicks work fine if the span isn't transitioning. If I set up static angles, you can click in the padded region of the link (not on the text) and it still detects the click. But if the text is rotating, somewhere around 70-110deg, it *consistently* doesn't catch the click.

Comment: do you need to register clicks when the item is in rotation? is it critical?

Comment: Yeah, since it's a link I need the user to be able to click the link without waiting for the rotation to finish. If they click during the rotation and the click doesn't work, the natural assumption is that the link simply isn't clickable. But good question, checkout the live (but not very publicized) project here: www.trickspoke.com

For this live site, the transition is pretty fast, minimizing the problem - even though it's still there.

Comment: I should add that you can tell it's not a basic hit-test problem in that you can see that the mouse is over a portion of the rotating span when it's clicked. It's just that somehow that click isn't being detected. Even if you use it as a standard <a href="something> tag, the browser does not navigate if the spinny span is clicked at the given angle range. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem. Since there are browser desparities using CSS, and even desparities between browsers, you will have issue using a pure CSS solution. You also have to realize that CSS actually collapses your divs when they are in the middle of an animation. our vision is not actually what is going on, its actually collapsing the div size to 0, meaning when you click you wont be able to "actually click it. below, shows you should put an absolute positioned div as an overlay and handle the click even from a clear, non visible div that will still have the illusion of you actually clicking a link.

```
<a id="link"></a>

 $("#link").click(function(){

spanClickCount++;
$("#SpanCounter").text(spanClickCount);

}
```

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I'm following you. What's overlapping the span? I've fiddled with the jsfiddle sandbox and removed the <span> tag and actually just simply removed places in the CSS where it references the span and we get a basic rotation. However that is even worse to click on, barely works. Maybe I missed something in converting it over.

Plus, my problem is that the .click() event simply isn't getting triggered at some of the specific angles. I wish I could just set the window.location but the code doesn't know when... :/

Comment: I never said to remove the <span> Just give your anchor an id and apply the click handler to the anchor. I tried it in your js fiddle and it worked even when rotating

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bsG3/4/ and it still fails for the same angles as before. :( Whatever is causing these mouse clicks not to be detected is very consistent in a given angle range. For testing, I'm specifically trying to click while the link is rotated at about a 90 (the first time the text rotates with it's flat side facing you). I know this seems like a corner case but when you see it on a real webpage, it becomes a big deal.

Comment: it works at all angles for me so I am not sure what your given issue is? also, why dont you just use  javascript window.location.href="http:///dfd" to the outer part of the div.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm testing in Chrome (25.0) & Firefox (19.0.2). I can't set window.location.href because I can't sense when the mouse is clicked (at the specific angles). I guess if you could see the problem, you'd see that it wouldn't work. :( If it's working for you, I really want to understand why it's NOT working for me!

Comment: chrome 25.....What I am asking is why dont you attach the click to a arbitrary "wrapper" span that doesn't spin, but when people click on it, it will still have the illusion that the "click" is from the spnning span?

Comment: Yeah, something invisible, absolutely positioned above each spinny link. That's the way to go at this point. I was hoping to get to the root cause - figuring that I can't be the only one to have seen this problem. But it's already past the time for that, time to just make it work now! Thanks for your suggestions, sorry I wasn't getting it at first!

Comment: sometimes things just are.. there are a ton of variables and unless you want your brain to rot, just make a work around..

Comment: I just fixed it this morning using absolutely positioned links above the spiny ones. With jQuery to handle the hover instead of CSS. It's a responsive site and so absolutely positioned invisible things just adds another set of stuff that can break. Plus I was hoping for a nice and pure CSS solution to that. But, even if we didn't get to the root cause, you did provide a fix for it. If you want to restate your answer clearly I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A element that is rotated so that it's backside is shown won't receive clicks on the backside, unless you specifically force the backside to be visible.

Use this on your span:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
   -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
    -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
     -o-backface-visibility: visible;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5bsG3/8/

Comment: AFAIK, `backface-visibility` is defaulted to `visible`. So that shouldn't change anything.

Comment: I'd accidentally set my backface-visibility to hidden, so this helped me find my issue. Thanks!